# How do I install LAMPP Full in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server, apt, lamp

Could you tell me please how to install LAMPP full in Ubuntu 16.04, I don't know what should I do with this part:

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

I know after that I should after use this one :

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

What should I do when executing this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS you can follow these steps to install Apache2, MySQL, PHP7 and `phpmyadmin`, I tested this today and it shouln't give you any kind of problems:

1. Install Apache2:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install apache2
   ```
2. Edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, add the following line at the end:

   ```
   ServerName <yourDomainOrIP>
   ```
3. Check if your config is OK:

   ```
   sudo apache2ctl configtest
   ```

   The output should be like this: `Syntax OK`
4. Restart Apache to implement changes:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
5. Verify if Apache is working, open you browser and go to: `http://your_ip_address`, you should see somehing like the following image:

   [image: Apache Works]
6. Install MySQL:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

   During this installation you will be asked to enter the MySQL password.
7. Secure your MySQL installation executing:

   ```
   sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```

   Choose the options that you prefer in this step.
8. Install PHP:

   ```
   sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
   ```
9. Edit the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`, after editing it should look like this:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_dir.c>
       DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
   </IfModule?
   ```
10. Restart Apache and check its status:

    ```
    sudo systemctl restart apache2
    sudo systemctl status apache2
    ```

    After this step if you want to install PHP modules, you can search for them using:

    ```
    apt-cache search php- | less
    ```
11. Test if PHP works, create an `info.php`:

    ```
    sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php
    ```

    An put the following content inside:

    ```
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
    ```

    Now go to `http://your_ip_address/info.php` and you should see something like the image below:

    [image: PHP Info]
12. Install `phpmyadmin`:

    ```
    sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
    ```

    During the installation you will be asked to choose your web server (apache2) and if you want to use `dbconfig-common` to configure the db, finally the password for `phpmyadmin` will be requested.

    This process adds `phpmyadmin` to `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`, you can verify it with: `ls /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`

    [image: ls /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/]
13. Enable PHP `mcrypt` and `mbstring`:

    ```
    sudo phpenmod mcrypt
    sudo phpenmod mbstring
    ```
14. Restart Apache again and test if everything works.

    ```
    sudo systemctl restart apache2
    ```

    Go to `http://your_ip_address/phpmyadmin` and you will see the login page:

    [image: phpmyadmin Login screen]

    Enter your credentials and then you're done:

    [image: phpmyadmin databases]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why do difficult? `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` and up to point 8 is done with a single command.